# Problema al abrir un programa con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema cuando intento abrir un programa me sale este mensaje de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet
```

¿Por qué sucede y qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentando ejecutar un código que utiliza twistedmatrix.

[Debes instalarlo](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads) antes de poder ejecutar el código.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el modulo que intentas abrir no está disponible en tu ruta $PYTHONPATH (o sys.path).

Deberias comprobar:

1. El módulo está instalado (suponiendo que usas linux tienes [este
   enlace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588390/how-do-i-check-whether-a-module-is-installed-or-not-in-python)). En caso de que no esté instalado, puedes instalarlo
   usando pip.
2. El módulo se encuentra dentro de la ruta ([aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path) puedes ver como
   hacerlo). En caso de que no este en la ruta, puedes hacer un
   sys.path.append('ruta_modulo')

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Tranquilos!!, no hace falta recibir tal avalancha por algo que he escrito haco poco mas de una hora. Lo he pillado y lo he editado. Saludos